# PhpStorm property annotation for instance of class

Tags: autocomplete, annotations, phpstorm

I know I can use PhpStorm annotations like this:

```
/**
 * Class Model
 * @property string name
 */
class Model {};

$modelInstance = new Model();
$modelInstance->name;
```

When I type `$modelInstance->` PhpStorm will offer me "name" in autocomplete.

**Is it possible to create custom property annotations for instances of classes?**

```
/**
 * Class Model
 * @property string name
 */
class Model {};

/**
 * @var Model $modelInstance @property text
 */
$modelInstance = new Model();
$modelInstance->text; //PhpStorm does not know about this property
```

I would like to have property "text" in PhpStorm autocomplete but ONLY for `$modelInstance`. Not for every instance of class Model.

Comment: Nope. `@property` can be declared in PHPDoc block for a **class only**. If you need something like that  .. then the best I can suggest is to declare custom class that extends your `Model` for that.

Comment: I wanted to use this with DibiRow object that is returned by Dibi when selecting data from database. So that I could tell phpstorm what columns I selected - what properties are available in my instance of DibiRow.

Comment: Well ... this is for PhpStorm only ... so you can try it and see how it will do for you: 1) create your own class `MyClass extends DibiRow` and declare such custom properties there; 2) Whenever you will need to use it, use `/** @var MyClass $modelInstance */` -- this PHPDoc comment will be used by IDE only; 3) Place file(s) with such custom classes anywhere in the project (e.g. `.phpstorm` folder etc) -- it will be used by IDE only.

Comment: The cons of such solution is very simple -- all these extra moves just for IDE to help you with code completion. That's one of the price aspects you have to pay for using magic methods/accessing non-existing properties (one class that suits every scenario). On another hand -- using own entity class for each DB Entity is a good solution anyway.

Comment: That is actually pretty cool. I can accept your comment as final answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my solution based on LazyOne's opinion.

```
/**
 *
 * Class ZboziDibiRow
 * @property int id
 * @property string name
 * @property string store
 * @property string uri
 * @property string manufacturer
 * @property string description
 * @property int price
 * @property string ean
 * @property string code
 * @property int available_in
 * @property string zbozi_category_id
 * @property string category_recursive_id
 */
class ZboziDibiRow extends DibiRow
{
}
```

Now when I have something like:

```
/**
* @var ZboziDibiRow[]
*/
public $products;
```

I will get autocomplete for:

```
$zbozi = new Zbozi();
foreach ($zbozi->products as $key => $product) {
    $product-> ....
```